# How to pass data from parent component to the children components along with props.match.params

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass some user info from Parent component to the child component but, am also passing props.match.params
In this case am getting data as undefined inside child component coming from parent as props.
Kindly focus on part highlighted with strings of hashtags.

I also want to pass props in Profile component along with getting access to props.match.params (props.match.params is working fine, but not able to send props to Profile )

```
function AuthorizedComponents(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header user={props.user} isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home user={props.user} isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/articles/:slug" component={Article}></Route>
        <Route path="/newpost">
          <NewPost user={props.user} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/settings">
          <Settings user={props.user} persistUser={props.persistUser} logOutUser={props.logOutUser} />
        </Route>
        ################################################
        <Route path="/profile/:username" exact  component={Profile}/>
         ################################################
        <Route path="*">
          <NoMatch />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: i think you can call the Profile component the same way you did with Home, NewPost and Settings components to be able to pass props to Profile

Comment: @DINO , but then , won't be able to use props.match.params.username in Profile component